# use phpmailer nameclass in php class

Tags: php, namespaces, phpmailer

I would like to use phpmailer at a php class, where should I place the default phpmailer namespace lines at the class?

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

my class:

```
require('./phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php');

class Email {

public function sent(){

}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `use` statements go at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually before anything else in the file, like this:

```php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php';

class Email {

    public function sent(){

    }
}
```

While I'm here, this is suspicious:

```
require('./phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php');
```

That looks like you're loading PHPMailer's own autoloader, which you shouldn't be going anywhere near. A typical project structure (e.g. all the examples provided with PHPMailer) would be something like:

```
/project
  /public
    index.php
  /app
    (app files go here)
  /vendor
    autoload.php
    /composer
    /phpmailer
```

Note that the autoloader is not in PHPMailer's own folder. In this kind of structure, the path to the autoloader from scripts in `public` or `app` folders will be:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

It may be that I'm being thrown off here because you have called your own project `phpmailer`, but I thought I'd flag it as it looks strange.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. But the autoload.php was created by composer within the phpmailer folder, can I just move the file up on level or should I re-composer it again with some parameter to make the autoload.php up one level? Thank you!

Comment: You must have made the `phpmailer` folder first – composer would not do that by default. It should be easy to start over: make a folder for your project, `cd` into it, run `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer`, and it will create everything in the right place.